# Xamarin Forms CustomCell in Listview Button Background binding not working?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a shared Xamarin.Forms project, and the problem only exists on Android. My problem is, that I have a listview, and when I click a button in my customcell, it changes color(from blue to green). Then I click another button which opens another page, and when I close that page, the item is removed from the listview. But now the item below the removed one, has a green button, instead of a blue.
Here's an example:

1. First image - Showing the ListView with a customcell inside containing information and 2 buttons, notice that they are blue.

[image]

2. Second image - Showing that I have pressed the first button, and it has now turned green.

[image]

3. Thrid image - Showing the page that is pushed when I press the second button.

[image]

4. Fourth image - Now I have clicked the "Bekræft" button on the image before, and the Message has been sent to the Listview page to remove the RouteElement from the list (and so it does). But now the first button is green, even though it has not been pressed.

[image]

The RouteElement Model.

```cs
 public class RouteElement : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    string arrivalBtnColor;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public bool ReadyForService { get; set; }
    public bool DeliveredToService { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalBtnBColor
    {
        get { return arrivalBtnColor; }
        set
        {
            if (arrivalBtnColor != value)
            {
                arrivalBtnColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ArrivalBtnBColor");
            }
        }
    }
    public RouteElement()
    {
        this.ArrivalBtnBColor = "Default";
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The CustomCell

```cs
Button ArrivalBtn = new Button
  {
    Text = "Ankomst",
    FontSize = 24,
    BorderRadius = 10,
    HeightRequest = 75,
    TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF")
  };
 ArrivalBtn.SetBinding(Button.BackgroundColorProperty, "ArrivalBtnBColor",BindingMode.Default, new StringToColorConverter(), null);

Label PostalNoLbl = new Label()
            {
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
            };
            PostalNoLbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Postcode");
            PostalNoLbl.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, "Postcode", BindingMode.Default,new StringToBoolConverter(),null);
```

Then I call this MessagingCenter function to remove, from another page in the navigation.

```cs
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<RouteElement>(this, "Refresh",(sender) =>
{
   RouteElement r = (RouteElement)sender;
   rOC.Remove(r);
}
```

And now the button of the second RouteElement is green, even though it's supposed to be blue. Any help is much appreciated!

This "bug" happens only on Android with the newest package of Xamarin.Forms

```xml
<package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.3.193" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
```

It works fine on Android with this package of Xamarin.Forms

```xml
<package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.2.0.31" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
```

Comment: can you share complete project to quickly reproduce the problem?

Comment: @YuriS - Can't do that.

Comment: A test project can be useful.

Comment: @JesperHøjer Without full code of your CustomCell it's hard to tell what is wrong

Comment: By looking at SetBinding syntax, you are using some third party library to set binding. Can you post source code of what SetBinding is doing? Also as @YuriS said, you need to post source code of CustomCell.

Comment: @AkashKava - It's a normal binding, no third party library used.

Comment: @YuriS - It's not about the customcell, I've given you the code of the button that is not working correctly, but it seems to be a problem with the catching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you defining a ListViewCachingStrategy for your ListView? You could try either:

```
_listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement);
```

or

```
_listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RetainElement);
```

The ListView may be incorrectly reusing the color (but not the text/content) from the old cell.

Comment: Currently testing you solution.

Comment: The RecycleElement, will work on the button, but it messes up the text in the custom cell, so it know is arranged to the left.

Comment: That's odd. Could you post the code for the text label in the CustomCell?

Comment: it has been added. i'm starting to think that it has something to do with the scrollingcache, do you know how to alter this in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: If it's just the Label now, try setting HorizontalAlignment to Center instead of HorizontalTextAlignment

Comment: Is still being tested, but seems to be working like it should with the tip from @woelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Works in 2.2x but not works in 2.3x.
2.3x has lots of bugs which can be read here

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77854/xamarin-forms-2-3-3-193/p2

**Developers suggest to use 2.2x because of the large number of bugs. I suggest the same.**